# getting errors in cocos 2dx game development environment setup on windows 8

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

Hi I am a novice programmer in cocos 2d-x. I have done programming in c/c++ before.
the problem im facing is i setup the environment according to the documentation but when i import the proj.android folder in the project there is an error that states:
   *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.

please help regarding this.
The Error displayed in the console is:

```
        09:48:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project HelloCpp ****
bash C:/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp/build_native.sh 
NDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Lapi-1\Desktop\WORKANDDEVELOPMENT\android-ndk-r8e
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /c/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp/../../..
APP_ROOT = /c/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /c/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp
Using prebuilt externals
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: /c/Users/Lapi-  1/workspace/HelloCpp/../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt    
jni/Android.mk:23: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos2dx' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
make.exe: Entering directory `/c/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp'
make.exe: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Lapi-1/workspace/HelloCpp'

09:48:47 Build Finished (took 5s.798ms)
```

Comment: the error is in the Android.mk file in the jni folder
it shows an error on
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
I linked the CocosDenshion folder to but no good...

Comment: can you show your error log

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me in similar form, when building the cpp-tests as part of the getting started tutorial. (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android for reference). I have windows 8 as well.

In my case, my cocos2d-x checkout via GitHub was apparently incomplete and missing some files (e.g. the freetype2 directory in my case). I downloaded the packaged zip from the website and that solved the problem. Perhaps your issue stems from missing files from the installation.

error log from command prompt:

```
Android NDK: C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\cocos2d-x\build\../cocos/./Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'freetype2/prebuilt/android' in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
make.exe: Entering directory `C:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/cocos2d-x/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android'
C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\cocos2d-x\build\../cocos/./Android.mk:218: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/cocos2d-x/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android'
Build dynamic library for project [ C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\cocos2d-x\build\..\tests/cpp-tests/proj.android ] fails!
```

The link to the downloads page: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download

Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Brad